# How to bitwise OR into a binary(100)?

Tags: mysql

I have a `binary(100)`, and I want to bitwise OR just one of its bytes with a constant.

Any idea how this would be done?

Alternatively, how can I store a value into a byte of a `binary(100)`?

Comment: @Alnitak: true, the functions have a 64bit limit. but nothing says you can't do string manipulations/casting to get at whatever byte/bit you want in a larger field.

Comment: @Nerfino what are you trying to store?  Does your data really need to be 100 contiguous bytes (would 13 eight-byte fields do?)  Are you aware of the space trimming "feature" in `binary` fields that could well mess up your bit fields?

Comment: What space trimming feature???

Comment: @Nerfino see last three paras of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/binary-varbinary.html

Comment: @Nerfino -actually that might only be an issue in older versions. It seems to have changed between 4.1 and 5.x

Comment: Oh good, because I was starting to think the MySQL people were crazy. I mean what's the point of calling something binary instead of varbinary if binary is effectively variable-length in certain situations as well? Furthermore why would it consider a "space" (I assume 0x20) to be special if the type is "binary"? I am starting to think SQL is like the VAX--- a crazy CISC-like architecture in need of replacement by something simpler and saner.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, consider whether `BINARY` is actually the appropriate field type.  When compared to `BLOB` it has a potentially nasty "feature" of stripping trailing spaces.  `BINARY` is really designed to be just a case-insenstive binary *text string*, and not a blob of arbitrary binary data.

If you do use a blob, you'd need to use the `SUBSTRING()` operator combined with `ASCII()` to extract just the byte you want, then use the `|` bitwise operator.

To set something in the second byte you'd need to use something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET col = CONCAT(
   SUBSTR(col, 1, 1),
   CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTR(col, 2, 1) | 0x80)),
   SUBSTR(col, 3)
)
```

A possibly simpler solution might be to treat your 100 bytes as 12.5 lots of 64 bits (i.e. `BIGINT`), and then use direct bitwise operations on individual words.