# Put 0 in a integer maskbit on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have to change the value of a determined column in postgre but I never worked before with maskbits, (it's a legacy code). The current value is 1 but it's stored as a integer maskbit so if I try to do

```
    update table set field=0 where ...
```

It doesn't work and it keeps returning me 1. So I read the documentation and tried to do a AND:

```
    update table set field=field&0 where ...
```

But it doesn't worked too. Then I tried to cover all the 30 bits, without success too:

```
    update table set field=field&0000000000000000000000000000000 where ...
```

Can someone please show me how to properly change the value of a integer maskbit on postgresql?

EDIT: I found [this case here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928899/6109438)

```
    UPDATE users SET permission = permission & ~16
```

which seen's to be the closest to mine so I tried to do

```
    UPDATE table SET field = field & ~1
```

because that's the only bit I have to deactivate but it still active and retuning 1 when I do a SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL may be pickier than you're used to when it comes to combining numbers of different types.  You can't just use a `0`, you need to use a bitstring constant of the right length, or explicitly cast an integer to the proper `bit(n)` type.

Bitstring constants are entered like `B'00101'`, which would have type `bit(5)`.
Some examples you can type into psql:

```
select 5;
select (5::bit(5));
select (30::bit(5));
select ~(1::bit(5));
select ~B'00001';
select (B'00101' & B'11110');
select (B'00101' & ~(1::bit(5)));
```

Comment: I've edited with a try I did. Using 'UPDATE table SET field = field & ~1' still's returning me 1, and if I try to use it as a Bit String, postgre returns errors about casting in the Update query.

Comment: You need to cast your `1` to the correct bitstring type, like `~(1::bit(5))`, except the `5` will probably need to be changed..  Type `\d tablename` in psql to see the proper type for your field.

Comment: Well it's a integer so I tried

'update table set field=field & ~(1::bit(32)) where ...'

But received the error "operator does not exist: integer & bit"

So I tried

'update table set field=field & ~(1::bit(32))::integer where ...'

Which returned

'Query returned successfully: one row affected, 166 ms execution time.'

But field keeps returning 1 when I SELECT

Comment: If the field is of type integer, then just `set field=0` or `set field = field & (~1)` should work.  Maybe something else is changing it back to 1 right after you clear it.

Comment: Forgive my mistake, yes there was another property setting this field back to 1 so I changed that and the "set field = field & (~1)" solved the problem. Thanks for the help!